# Page jumps to the top of the page even when using an Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I'm running into a bit of an issue. I have some asp.net controls wrapped in an update panel, but when I click the submit button it jumps to the top of the page. I've read a bunch of posts on here, and they either require use of some javascript or say set the MaintainPagePostion to "true" in the page directive. I tried setting it to true, that did not work. I really don't want to use a javascript script to accomplish this either. I was under the impression that this is one of the benefits to using an update panel. However, the part that I find most confusing, is it used to not do this. I don't remember changing anything on the website that would have caused this. Any help with this problem is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailStuff" runat="server">
        Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="202px"></asp:TextBox><br />
        Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="203px"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; margin-left:55px;">**Please double check email**</span><br />
        Message:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Width="370px" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" Height="75px"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailError" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label> 
        <asp:ImageButton Height="25px" Width="60px" CssClass="EmailSubmit" ImageUrl="Images/MailingListBtnSubmit2.png" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlThankYou" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size:30px;">Thank you!<br /><span style="font-size:20px;">Your Email has been sucessfully submitted.</span></p>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Well I think I know what's killing me. I have some page routing in my application. I made a copy of the project and deleted the code in my global.asax file for the page routes, and it works like it used to.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in 4 ways :

1. From Code-behind - `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;`
2. From Page Directive - `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`
3. From Web.config - `<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />`
4. Using Javascript. You can use the code from following link. It worked for me -

http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx

Comment: By the way, what browser you are using? Sometimes, these are purely browser specific issues and in this cases, javascript is the best option as these codes resides on clientside and independent of rendering issues.

Comment: I tried Chrome and Fire Fox. I have already tried #3. Thanks for the response though. I read somewhere that the maintain scroll position is only for IE.

Comment: For the same reason, javascript is the best option in this case. Most browsers has strong and identical support for this language.

Comment: i used 4° solution, js, fine thank u! with the 1° nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's not jump to the top of the page. It's refreshing the page. What's your update panel's UpdateMode? Is it Conditional? If it's conditional, check trigger. ControlID should be button ID and EventName='Click'. Then check the area of Update Panel .

Sample Code Here :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailStuff" runat="server">
        Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="202px"></asp:TextBox><br />
        Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="203px"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; margin-left:55px;">**Please double check email**</span><br />
        Message:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Width="370px" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" Height="75px"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailError" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label> 
        <asp:ImageButton Height="25px" Width="60px" CssClass="EmailSubmit" ImageUrl="Images/MailingListBtnSubmit2.png" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlThankYou" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size:30px;">Thank you!<br /><span style="font-size:20px;">Your Email has been sucessfully submitted.</span></p>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried setting the update mode to conditional and adding the trigger. Like I said, it used to be fine. That's why I'm so confused. I edited my post to show the code I'm using. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Randell, I added sample code to my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the triggers in the update panel? If you specify the triggers in the triggers section then the update panel will update without jumping on top.Also you need to give **updatemode = "conditional"**. It can be done like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ex" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
//your controls here
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="yourbuttonid" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: try keeping this in your submit button click event: UpdatePanel1.Update()

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you to everyone that gave me suggestions. As it turns out the Page Routing is what caused this issue. So all I had to do to get it working was add and ignore line for that page in my RegisterRoutes code block:

```
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("Mobile");
        routes.Ignore("Booking.aspx*");//<---- This Fixed it.
        routes.MapPageRoute("Gallery", "Gallery/{Name}", "~/Gallery.aspx");
        routes.Ignore("*");//<---- This is better for me. It acts as a catch all.
    }
```

This helped me solve the issue: http://forums.asp.net/t/1743640.aspx

*EDIT*

I added the "routes.Ignore("*");" code to it to act as a catch all, so I really don't need to ignore "Booking.aspx" specifically. Keep in mind though the order is important here. The Ignore("*") needs to be the last one or else none of the other routing will work.

Thanks again Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try PageRequestManager handlers

```
<script>
              Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);



        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            try {

                sender._controlIDToFocus = null;


            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck for a few hours with a similar problem. I was convinced the problem was the **UpdatePanel** but it ended up being the **defaultfocus** & **defaultbutton** attributes in the form tag that was causing the page to jump up to focus the first textbox at the top of the page.

`<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="buttonId" defaultfocus="textboxId">`

This is something else to look at when facing this kind of issue.